# PL/SQL oracle. удаление всех символов из строки до определенного символа VARCHAR2

Tags: sql, строки, oracle, plsql

В поле есть значения типа VARCHAR2 вида

```
|LOG                            |
---------------------------------
|192.168.1.5 (IE\PC7777/59593)  |
|192.168.2.3 (ER\PC77/55432)    |
|192.168.6.3 (OY\PC123/director)|
|10.11.2.5 (PR\PC772/buha)      |
```

Нужно обработать значения так, чтобы получить результат

```
|LOG     |
----------
|59593   |
|55432   |
|director|
|buha    |
```

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions164.htm#SQLRF06303

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используем функцию `REGEXP_REPLACE`

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(LOG,'(.$)|(.+\/)','') AS LOG FROM MYTABLE
```